# Automatically open and position eight webpages across four 3840 x 2160 screens (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, screen, autohotkey, monitor

I need to find a way to trigger the opening and positioning of eight live webpages across four screens. I am currently using this [AHK Workspaces - Window Management AutoHotkey Script](https://hackerspace.kinja.com/ahk-workspaces-window-management-autohotkey-script-1773712225), but I am finding that it's inconsistent. The hotkey trigger will only work half the time and the webpages don't always open to the pre-defined positions. I feel this script would be perfect for multiple application windows, including a web browser, but since I'm trying to trigger multiple webpages (all currently Firefox, but I'm flexible), it's becoming messy. I'm open to writing my own code to get this working, but I don't know where to start and would really appreciate some advice.

Essentially, once I have this first phase working, I'll want to develop a second phase with four webpages across the four screens (one webpage per screen, all maximised). Then I'd want to set it to a schedule, where the first phase is triggered and runs for 45 minutes, then the second phase is triggered and runs for 15 minutes and so on.

Any help or guidance would be truly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand fully what you are trying to achieve.

My recommendation would be to create a basic Winform app, that run fullscreen with 4 WebBrowser controls and code to manage the refresh. cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms

You could also create display a single webpage on each screen containing an iframe that displays the target contents, and some JavaScript code to manage the rolling.
cf. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond Matthieu.

I'm aiming to achieve the following:

 - Screen One: two webpages side by side, occupying half the screen each
 - Screen Two: three webpages, one taking up the lhs of the screen and the two others split horizontally over the rhs 
 - Screen Three: one maximised webpage 
 - Screen Four: two webpages split vertically (stacked), occupying half of the screen each.


I'll have a look into your recommendations.